# Operator norm of special lower triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Is there a way to compute the singular values of $n \times n$ matrix:
$$ 
A_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{i} & i\geq j, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Is there a way to compute the singular values of $A \circ A$, where $\circ$ is the Hadarmard product?

I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ is $1,1/2, \cdots, 1/n$ and $PDP^{-1} = A$, where $P$ is the lower triangular matrix with entries forming the Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but a bit long for a comment and it highlights that it is unlikely to have a formula for the singular values.

Calculating the $3\times 3$ case, the singular values of $A$ are
\begin{align}
\lambda_1&=\sqrt{\frac{11}{18} + \frac89\, \cos\Big(\frac13 \arctan\frac{9 \sqrt{1967}}{943}\Big)},\\[0.3cm]
\lambda_2&=\sqrt{\frac{11}{18}+\frac{ 4\sin\Big(\frac13 \arctan\frac{9 \sqrt{1967}}{943}\Big)}{3\sqrt3}- \frac49\, \cos\Big(\frac13 \arctan\frac{9 \sqrt{1967}}{943}\Big)},\\[0.3cm]
\lambda_3&=\sqrt{\frac{11}{18}-\displaystyle\frac{4 \sin\Big(\frac13 \arctan\frac{9 \sqrt{1967}}{943}\Big)}{3\sqrt3}- \frac49\, \cos\Big(\frac13 \arctan\frac{9 \sqrt{1967}}{943}\Big)}.\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}
Maybe someone can figure out a formula out of this, but not me.

For $A\circ A$ the situation looks even worse. Again in the $3\times 3$ case, we have
\begin{align}
\lambda_1&= \sqrt{\frac{251}{648} + \frac{\sqrt{50581} }{324} \,\cos\Big(\frac13 \,\arctan\frac{54 \sqrt{1036894827}}{11242097}\Big)}, \\[0.3cm]
\lambda_2&= \sqrt{\frac{251}{648} + \frac1{216}\,\frac{\sqrt{50581} }{3} \,\sin\Big(\frac13 \,\arctan\frac{54 \sqrt{1036894827}}{11242097}\Big)-\frac{\sqrt{50581} }{648} \cos\Big(\frac13 \,\arctan\frac{54 \sqrt{1036894827}}{11242097}\Big)}, \\[0.3cm]
\lambda_3&= \sqrt{\frac{251}{648} - \frac1{216}\,\frac{\sqrt{50581} }{3} \,\sin\Big(\frac13 \,\arctan\frac{54 \sqrt{1036894827}}{11242097}\Big)-\frac{\sqrt{50581} }{648} \ \cos\Big(\frac13 \,\arctan\frac{54 \sqrt{1036894827}}{11242097}\Big)}, \\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I had the same feeling; however, their ratio seems to be converging on something around 0.6. I am trying to find an upper bound on $A \circ A$ and a lower bound on $A$ which allows me to show this convergence.